# Is it safe to shut off an electric water heater for long periods of time?

Tags: water, water-heater, hot-water, usa, florida

The house is located in Florida and has a 4 year old electrical water heater.  Can I safely shut off the hot water heater for a long period of time? Or can I install a regulator and the purpose of it?

Comment: Should define a long period.   Weeks or more should probably drain the tank also.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is it that you're trying to accomplish by turning off the heater? What is a "long" time? What kind of regulator do you want to install - what are you trying to regulate?

Comment: Note that if you're draining the tank, it _must_ be refilled _before_ turning on the hot water heater. Running the element (if electric) unloaded will cause it to overheat and burn out

Comment: Are you interested in knowing how dangerous that water might become if drank, or only whether the equipment will be ok?

Comment: @Wanda, could you please [edit] your question to clarify what you want to know about the regulator, and more importantly, what you're trying to accomplish by turning off the heater? Also, what would constitute  "a long period of time"? Days? Weeks? Months? Years?

Answer (score 13):

All hot water heaters already have a regulator.  Otherwise the water would boil over and you'd have a boiler explosion.

You can feel free to shut off an electric water heater for an extended period of time. You can switch it off at the circuit breaker, a local disconnect if it has one, or the thermostat. If the breaker is reasonably modern I would use that, less likely to break.

Try not to switch it off every day.  It won't save *that much* power, and the water will spend a lot of time at medium temperatures between hot and cold. That's a breeding ground for bacteria.

Comment: Switching the water heater on and off every day is something we do regularly here in Eastern Europe, usually by a built-in or external timer. Electricity is a lot cheaper at night. On the other hand, bacteria colonies need time to develop. It is OK to heat it to over 65C only once in a week.

Comment: External timers are/were a thing here in the US as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the cycles of cold and then heat will be over long intervals (months), then it shouldn't be a problem. Maybe check the tank's reservoir for bacteria buildup once in awhile, and change the entire reservoir's contents out if they appear. (They aren't a health hazard, because the water you use passes through a coil that sits in the reservoir, and the two don't mix. But grunge clogs maintenance valves, and that's never good.)

FYI: Switching off the heater shouldn't be done repeatedly in short cycles, such as for a weekend vacation home. Each cycle stresses the metal parts slightly, and may cause problems with seals after some large number of cycles (I'd guess a thousand or more. The number will vary with the model. Ask the mfr if you're concerned; they have this data from their product testing.) In that case, a better solution is to lower the temp by 30º or so when not using it, rather than a full shut-off.

Comment: "The water you use passes through a coil that sites in the reservoir, and the two don't mix"  Indirect water heaters (having a separate boiler unit) are quite rare IME.  Far more common to directly heat the single supply reservoir.

Comment: you can tell a combined boiler heat exchanger unit because the temperature/pressure relief valve water flows into the boiler  and the boiler has an open vent/drain outlet.  it's not the same thing as indirect at all. they tend to die from cracking of the (ourput) heat exchanger coil.  possibly due to thermal cycling or water hammer.

Answer (score 1):

A rental house I lived in for a few years had the water heater on an automatic timer. It would turn on a couple of hours before we needed it in the morning and then shut off around 9 or so at night.

It was like that for the threeish years we lived there and never had an issue that I'm aware of.